# Указание первоначального адреса элемента массива

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Был дан массив из 3-х разрядных числа,необходимо было найти суммы цифр каждого числа и выстроить их по убыванию с **указанием** их первоначальных адресов.

pascal,

```
    program lab19_1;
const n = 10;
var a,b:array[1..n] of integer;
    i,k,j,x: integer;

function f(x:integer):integer;
var
  d,s: integer;
begin
  s:=0;
  while x > 0 do
   begin
    d:= x mod 10;
    s:= s + d;
    x:= x div 10;
   end;
   f:=s;
end;


procedure swap(var x,y: integer);
   var t: integer;
 begin
    t := x;
    x := y;
    y := t
 end;

begin
randomize;
writeln('Исходный массив');
for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    a[i]:=random(100)+500;
    write(i,' эл. = ',a[i],' ');
  end;
writeln;
writeln('Cумма цифр в числе,без сортировки');  
for i:=1 to n do
 a[i] := f(a[i]);
for i:=1 to n do
  write(' y ',i,' эл. = ',a[i], ' ');
//метод пузырька
for i:=1 to n-1 do
 for j:=i+1 to n do
  if a[i] < a[j] then
   swap(a[i],a[j]);
writeln('Новый массив');
for i:=1 to n do
write(a[i],' ');
readln;
end.
```

Не могу приложить ума,что нужно сделать дальше? Как указать первоначальный адрес?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Тебе необходим массив записей, который будет хранить:**

1) индекс числа до сортировки

2) само число

**Структура выглядит так:**

```
Type YourType=record
   number:indeger;
   indexPrev:byte;
end;
Type ArrYourType = array[1..n] of YourType;
```

Заполняешь `indexPrev` числами от 1 до n;

И далее делаешь сортировку.

После этого ты будешь знать индекс первоначального расположения этого числа в массиве

Comment: А что такое record?

Comment: http://www.pascal.helpov.net/index/pascal_record_programming

Comment: cпасибо,за три года на паскале ни разу не встречал record (